# should I use str_replace() or is there a better drupal way for that?

Tags: tokens

Some background info:
I'm Building a D7 module that also sends out a message to users of the site.
I want the site maintainers to be able to define the message by using 'tokens' like this:

```
$string = "hello :username, there is a new node called :nodenodename_with_a_link on the :website"; // defined in the GUI
```

I could use str_replace to replace those 'tokens' like so:

```
$find = array(':username', ':nodenodename_with_a_link', ':website');
$replace = array($username, $node, $sitename); // generated form the db
$newstring = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

But I'm wondering if this is also the correct way to go in Drupal (7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create your own tokens in a custom module or use `strtr` (it's easier for multiple search and replace operations than str_replace).

To see how to create custom tokens and integrate with token module see `token_example` module in [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: I knew it there had to be a 'cleaner' drupal way thanks for pointing me to the token_example!

Comment: hmm just now I realize I could use the t() function for this... ?

Comment: You're welcome - glad I helped :)

Comment: Yes, you could use that one as well.